# JQ : Select arrays both top level and nested

Tags: jq

I have multiple files containing both A array elements at the top level, and files containing A array elements nested in B elements. Is it possible to extract the data in a single jq line?

File 1:

```
{ "A" : [ 
  { "x" : " y" } 
  ] 
}
```

File 2:

```
{ "B" : [ 
  { "A" : [ 
    { "x" : "y" } 
  ] } 
] }
```

I have tried the following command

```bash
jq -r 'select(.A[] != null or .B[].A[] != null) | .A[] | .x'
```

without expected results.

Comment: `select` does not traverse to where the check evaluates to `true`. It just passes the input (the full document in this case), which is why the subsequent `.A[]` might still fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be straightforward with using `getpath/1`. Dynamically identify all paths where the leaf value is `A`

```
getpath(paths | select(.[-1] == "A")) | .[].x
```

jqplay - [Demo 1](https://jqplay.org/s/OfVvqAcL9v6), [Demo 2](https://jqplay.org/s/m5upaXcphRd)

or a hacky-way to rely on the fact that `A` is an array and `x` will always be one of the leaf paths

```
getpath(paths | select(.[-3] == "A" and .[-1] == "x"))
```

To visualize how the solution works, run the command `paths` on your input JSON, which breaks down the original JSON to all possible root-leaf paths. `getpath/1` works by getting the value at a given path, where the last element in the array i.e. `-1` is the leaf path `x` and 2 places before last is `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `.[]?` (see the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D%3F)) which works

> like `.[]`, but no errors will be output if `.` is not an array or object.

```bash
jq -r '., .B[]? | .A[]?.x'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/30_rblyue0Q)